# Grafana import a simple json file as data source

Tags: json, grafana, honeypot

I have a bunch of data in a JSON file.
I would like to use that as (static) data source in Grafana, but I don't know how to do that.

I have installed Grafana (in a Docker container) and have added the [Simple JSON](https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource) plugin. But to my understanding that takes as input a URL... not a JSON file :( How can I do that?

I've had a look at the [Fake JSON data source example](https://github.com/bergquist/fake-simple-json-datasource/blob/master/index.js). I see it implements a web server that will answer to some typical requests like /search or /query. But I don't understand how to adapt that. I am pretty new to Grafana as you can see...

This is what my json looks like:

```
{"eventid": "cowrie.direct-tcpip.request", "timestamp": "2019-01-15T10:03:24.604331Z", "session": "f3f60d4e", "src_port": 0, "message": "direct-tcp connection request to xxxx:443 from ::1:0", "system": "SSHService ssh-connection on HoneyPotSSHTransport,874,xxxxxx", "isError": 0, "src_ip": "xxxxxxxx", "dst_port": 443, "dst_ip": "xxxx", "sensor": "90a9ea4c9756"}
```

Thanks for your help.